# Project VB to C# - String to Int32 or Decimal not working

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have converted a working VB project from VS2010 to C# in VS2015 but now the string to Int / decimal is no longer working...and for the life of me cant find out why.

To issue is when the page loads the RowDataBound triggers (Working correctly) but I have `if` triggers to highlight cells based on values, but they dont seem to work..

So can you can see from the code below, I have tried decimal (All values return as 0 so no triggers happen), I've tried int32 all triggers still show as 0, so I think its the conversion between the SQL data and the convert to int.

Any ideas as I'm at my wits end here :(.

p.s data has to have decimal places but needs to be compared as If value is greater than 45 or if value is between 40 and 45 (or 44.999999999)

-EDIT-

The code below shows both types of code I have tried (both failed) and the issue is converting the `e.Row.Cells[y].Text` section to a useable decimal / int function.

-End Edit-

How the data is stored
[image: SQL Data in Excel form for ease of copying]

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    string testValue = e.Row.Cells[3].Text;

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
    }

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int d = 3; d <= 22; d++)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[d + 1].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[d].ToolTip = e.Row.Cells[d + 1].Text;

            d = d + 1;
        }

        e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;

        for (int y = 3; y <= 22; y++)
        {
            Decimal testval;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Row.Cells[y].Text)) 
                return;

            Decimal.TryParse(e.Row.Cells[y].Text,out testval);
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(testval);

            if (n > 44.999999)
            {
                if (testval < 45)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[y].Attributes.Add("Style", "background-color: orange;");
                    e.Row.Cells[y].ForeColor = Color.Black;
                }
            }

            if (testval > 44.9999999999999)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[y].Attributes.Add("Style", "background-color: red;");
                e.Row.Cells[y].ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }

            y = y + 1;

            if (testval > 0)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[23].Attributes.Add("Style", "background-color: red;");
                e.Row.Cells[23].ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }

        for (int x = 3; x <= 22; x++)
        {
            int testval1;

            int.TryParse(e.Row.Cells[x].Text, out testval1);
            if (testval1 == 0)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[x].Text = "Rest";
            }
            x = x + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Int doesn't have decimals. This line  _int n = Convert.ToInt32(testval);_ truncates everything and the following if line makes no sense

Comment: And why not use d+=2 for readability.

Comment: I know this is wrong and hence why I showed the code with both processes I tried.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, the d = d + 1 is done because one the columns that have been removed data is stored and used as a tooltip, so the standard +1 from the 'next' or end of the loop doesnt cut it. The issue I'm having is the Decimal.TryParse(e.Row.Cells[y].Text,out testval); section, its getting the e.row.cells[y].text to a decimal

Comment: *What* doesn't work about `Decimal.TryParse(e.Row.Cells[y].Text,out testval);`? I appreciate you're then converting it to an integer on the very next line, which will lose the fractional part, but does the value show correctly in the debugger before that?

Comment: @RowlandShaw it seems that the value never infact gets to `testval' as that always seems to be zero, which implies to me that the `Parse` is failing? I'm extremely new to C# so most of this is from the VB to C# converter and alot of googling, however I'm at the point now that google doesn't resolve the issue (hence why I'm here)

Do you think its due to how the data is stored within SQL? As its stored as Decimal(18,2) so get values like 38.27 etc, and it shows when I debug and hover over 'e.row.cells[y].text' as "38.27" but cant get it out of the string to a decimal :(

Comment: What does `Decimal.TryParse(e.Row.Cells[y].Text,out testval)` return? `false`? what is the value of `e.Row.Cells[y].Text`  that fails?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Can see that the value on the first run is "38.27" by hovering over `e.Row.Cells[y].Text` but testval = 0 afterwards. Not sure how to tell if it failed / succeeded (other than testval being > 0) or returned though.

Comment: FFSSS! @RowlandShaw you're a legend, you reminded me that VS2010+ can sometimes be abit 'stupid' so it didnt pick up that testval had changed from Int to decimal and was still giving me 'type INT' in the debugger, so I cleaned / rebuilt and built the project again and its working now...

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that VS2015 was still picking up `testval` as int even though it was changed to decimal, a clean / rebuild fixed this.